# Sum int with char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, sum

During my examination of some existing code, I came across this line:

```
char *s = malloc(SIZE);
scanf("%s", s);
char *y = s + strlen(s);
```

Assuming the `scanf()` function succeed, what's the meaning of adding an integer to a char array?

My expectation was to get a new string that contains the content of `s` and another char with the ASCII code of the integer (or at least, the original string).

By debugging this code it seems it seems that `y=""` after the operation.

What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: `s + strlen(s);` performs pointer arithmetic, it doesn't create a "new string"

Comment: It is an offset.

Comment: A better way might have been `char *y = strchr(s, '\0');`

Comment: "adding integer to char array" ... Wrong. What is being done is adding integer to char pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen(s)` finds the length of the string, which also happens to be the index of the terminating `\0` character.

Adding an integer to a pointer finds a pointer that is that many elements further along in memory. The expression `s + strlen(s)` therefore adds the length of `s` to the pointer value. This means that it computes a pointer that points to the `\0` character.

An equivalent way of doing the same, which may be more concise is

```
char *y = strchr(s, '\0');
```

Answer (score 5):

It's probably clearer to write this in the form of an array indexing operation rather than pointer arithmetic.

```
int n;
char* y = s + n;
char* y = &s[n];
```

These two forms are equivalent. `s` is the address of the first element in the array. Adding one to it gives you the address of the next element in the array, and so on. Both expressions evaluate to the address of the n'th element in the array, assuming that the array is large enough. In this case, y points at the null terminator at the end of the string.

Comment: I didn't say better. I said probably clearer. The OP was confused by the arithmetic expression (hence the question) so I thought that explaining the equivalence between that and the array indexing expression would help matters.

Comment: My mistake. +1 to you sir.